# Unmount USB device in sandboxed Mavericks application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, usb, osx-mavericks, appstore-sandbox

i wrote a sandboxed app which deals with USB drives under Yosemite (10.10).
When the app is done with its stuff i want to offer the user an option to eject the device.

Under Yosemite thats not a problem, i successfully used

```
DADiskUnmount()
```

and

```
[NSWorkspace unmountAndEjectDeviceAtURL:error:]
```

But under Mavericks (10.9) both methodes won't work.
I double checked my whole code and i'm pretty confident there are no SDK conflicts.

I get the following error message

```
Sandbox denied authorizing right 'system.volume.external.unmount' by client <MyApp>
```

I got all USB related entitlements, use security-scoped bookmarks (with startAccessingSecurityScopedResource and without), repaired disk permissions on the test device, used different kinds of USB devices to test, checked if there are open files on the device and tried kDADiskUnmountOptionForce.

The

```
system.volume.external.(adopt|encode|mount|rename|unmount)
```

authorization right only appears on 10.8 and 10.9. source:[link](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-right/system-volume-external-wildcard.html)

Is there a way to grant my app this right ?

It would be nice if someone could help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aperture uses the sandbox ["big red button"](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2438/the-sandboxs-big-red-button) (`com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl`) to do `system.volume.external.mount`/`unmount`.

From [Aperture's entitlements file](https://github.com/nikf/apple-app-sandbox/blob/master/aperture.txt):

`<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl</key>
    <string>
        (begin
            (allow authorization-right-obtain (right-name "system.volume.external.mount"))
            (allow authorization-right-obtain (right-name "system.volume.external.unmount"))
            (deny network-outbound (with no-log)
                    (regex #"^/private/tmp/launch-"))
            (allow file-ioctl
                    (literal "/dev/ptmx")
                    (literal "/dev/null")
                    (literal "/dev/tty")
                    (regex #"^/dev/ttys"))
            (allow file-search)
            (allow ipc-posix-sem)
            (allow system-fsctl))
    </string>`

No idea whether Apple will allow this in the MAS though.

Comment: hey! now i want to submit this to the MAS... could you possibly explain each line or give me a link to a ressource where i can read up this informations ? i want to properly explain why i wrote this in my entitlement file so it may get accepted.

Comment: Hmm I guess just tell the truth, that it's in Aperture's entitlements file and ejecting doesn't work under Mavericks without it.  Have you tried removing some of the other lines though? Like just leave the "allow authorization-right-obtain" line for unmount and see if it works? They're probably more likely to approve it with less allowed.

Comment: it works when i just leave allow authorization-right-obtain (right-name "system.volume.external.unmount) ... rigth now i'm waiting for the review :)